# Get Rotation in degrees (0-360) from a rotated angle?

Tags: geometry, rotations

I have a rectangle that is facing up. ($0^\circ$)

I'm getting a number bettween $-1000$ to $1000$ or even more, and this number is the angle that is rotating the rectangle.

How can I know the degrees it is facing now?

Comment: Rotating by $360^\circ$ is equivalent to not rotating at all, so just keep adding or subtracting multiples of it until you get something in $[0,360]$. (More specifically, $x\to x-360\lfloor x/360\rfloor$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).) Also... *he*?

Comment: Cool it works :)
but why didn't you put it as answer ? lol

Comment: Also, if your programming language (I assume you're doing this in a computer program) has an [fmod](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.7.html#fmod) function or something equivalent, $x \mapsto \operatorname{fmod}(x, 360)$ is probably easier than $x \mapsto x - 360 \cdot \lfloor x/360 \rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in a comment:

> Rotating by $360^{\circ}$ is equivalent to not rotating at all, so just keep adding or subtracting multiples of it until you get something in $[0,360]$. (More specifically, $x\mapsto x−360⌊x/360⌋$, where $⌊\cdot⌋$ is the floor function.) –  anon Aug 28 '11 at 9:05

Answer (score 0):

If the angle $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$, you may also use the remainder of $\alpha$ when divided by 360. Implementing this on a computer, you then could use the modulo operation which is quite efficient (compared to a division, a floor and a multiplication) and in most languages shorter to type (e.g. alpha%360 in C++)